# Graphics card compatiblity with windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

When I run certain games the error message:

No suitable display modes were found

Appears

Background:

I recently upgraded my computer to a Windows 8.1 HP Envy. The games installed fine. However when I tried to run the game it failed with the 'Spooge Driver' error message.

I managed to fix this by updating the list of graphics cards in my direct X driver directory.
but then for another game this "No Suitable Display modes were found" message appears and doesn't let me run the game.

I have tried running in Compatibility Mode (XP) to no avail.

So, what can I do to get a 'suitable display mode' and stop Windows 8.1 throwing that error?

Quick computer Specs:

Graphics card Nvidia Geforce GTX 760 (192-bit)

16 GB RAM

Beats Audio

Also the games I am trying to run are old, the likes that are compatible with XP and below. but I had these certain games work fine on a windows 7 machine...

Comment: You really have no provided us any  helpful information.  The peice of information that is required is your dxdiag report.

Comment: You need to also explain and detail exactly what you mean you updated the list of graphic cards in the direct x driver directory.  Programs can target specific versions and multiple versions of direct x can be installed.  We need speciifcs to help you.

Comment: The games run Direct X 9 But I have the latest version installed on my machine. I can link you to the question in Arqade? that is specific to one game but it is happening on other games so I thought it my be a hardware problem. I will find the specific direct X Directory I edited too and comment that.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161636/warhammer-40k-pc-game-not-playing-on-windows-8-1 the first answer the part marked "Desperate Times"

Comment: You having the most recent version of Direct X 9 installed tells me nothing. As I indicated. A program can target a specific version of Direct X 9, there are several dozen I would estimate, only the version targeted would work with the program in question. This is the reason Staam for example will install the specific version of Direct X that is required. **We don't like cross-posting questions.** This question should be self-contained on this website.  I cannot even vist that site because of website filtering.